Chopper Opamp PNoise Simulation
I am simulating the output noise spectrum (node VO) of a chopper opamp, the schematic of which is shown below.

These are the simulation results I had from noise and pnoise simulations. Due to chopping, I would expect to see some sort of peaking at multiples of chopping frequency (fchop). This is due to the fact that flicker noise is modulated to multiples of fchop. However, as shown in the simulation result, the curve remains relatively flat. I'm unsure why the curve remains flat even at 1MHz, where flicker noise should be modulated to.
Thank you very much
Updates:

Testbench for my simulation.  One chopper is outside of the op and the other is inside the op.



Simulation Settings (Noise and PNoise)

Noise Analysis

PNoise Analysis


Simulation Results (Noise and PNoise)


Update with log-log scale of the above figure.

Update: Refsideband = -1, 0, 1


Why not show the simulation schematic?

Is "pnoise" supposed to be "pink noise" and "noise" is supposed to be.... "white noise"?

@Colin pnoise in cadence should be periodic steady state noise (which draws from pss output data). OP: could you please include the ADE settings for the pss+pnoise analysis in your post, along with the schematic Andy requested?

@Colin pnoise is the standard periodic noise simulation in Cadence.

@Kenlucius is the x-axis offset frequency or absolute?

@Andyaka I have updated the original edit to include simulation testbench, simulation setups and simulation results for your reference.

@a360pilot x-axis is absolute frequency. I have included my settings of Pnoise for your reference.

Draw your noise plot with the noise axis in dB (and maybe linear frequency axis): log or log-log plot. The harmonics may be too small to be discernible in linear scale with the noise this great

@V.V.T I have updated the log-log scale of the noise plow.

Try setting refsideband = 1 or refsideband = -1. Your noise components after chopping lie around the first sideband.

@a360pilot Thank you very much for your reply. Just gave resideband = -1, 0, 1 a test.  Please see the above simulation result. The variable ref_side = refsideband. The three seem to have the same result.

Do you need the answer to account for the aliasing inherent to having too high an input freq for the chopper frequency?

@ScottSeidman Thank you very much for your reply. I'm sorry that I'm not sure on the phenomenon of "aliasing inherent to having too high an input frequency". Could you please show me a little more?

A chopper amp is effectively a sampled system, so sampling theorem applies.  The input should be frequency limited to less than half the chopper frequency.

@ScottSeidman Thank you for your reply. As far as I know, chopping is considered a continuous-time modulation technique and it does not have the noise penality typical of the auto-zero techniques. The sampling theorem perhaps is less relevent here.

Yes, sampling theory starts at modulation theory.  Similar math

In modulation, you're multiplying two signals.  For sampling, one of those signals is an impulse train.

Thank you very much Scott. I sincerely appreciate your help. I think I will have some more readings on such theories


I'm unsure why the curve remains flat even at 1MHz, where flicker noise should be modulated to.

I believe you made a good job of designing your Cadence circuit and simulation, but your question seems to belong in a signal processing rather than electrical engineering domain. Let me consider the problem    of cancelling 1MEG ripple in a good implementation with a very simple model, where choppers are mixers with 180 degree shifted LO inputs to one another and filtering before the second chopper is made with a simple sinc filter. In this model, almost all of the low-frequency 1/f noise is discarded perfectly, only a portion of 1/f noise passes to the output, and this portion is proportional to the bandpass window and therefore it is small. However, your plots show a noticeable 1/f PSD is present in the output signal, and I recommend you try and detect the source of 1/f noise in your circuit other than the IF amplifier before the second chopper.
As the question is more of a signal processing variety, you can examine the working principle with a Python program I coded for this purpose.
First, I try to reconstruct the OP graphs with a very simple model of chopper amplifier.
Let's start with the narrow-band IF amplifier which is very narrow band, 10Hz bandwidth amplifier; no input signal is fed to the circuit input (VIN = Vcm = 0.9V). Flicker noise is generated exclusively in the narrow-band signal amplifier ('IF' amplifier) path and there are no other sources of flicker noise in the circuit:

At the circuit output, the low-frequency component of internal flicker noise (below a chopper frequency) is filtered out, and the chopper harmonics, starting with the first harmonic (2 MHz), appear in the chopper2_out graph, as expected. No fundamental chopper tone (1 MHz) can be seen, as the chopper waveform (square wave) is antisymmetric.
The chopper2 output is well below -100 dB, so a comparatively low-power flicker noise, added to this signal, conceals the chopper harmonics and the graph starts to qualitatively resemble the OP graphs. Notice that this extra low-power flicker noise ('parasitic' flicker noise) certainly would appear at the output of real amplifier circuits of any configuration. It is tolerated because the power of this interference can be made negligible by an experienced designer, while with a wide-band amplifier the flicker noise is often an insurmountable problem:

The output level, with added flicker, increases by 70 dB, but is still well below -60dB. No traces of harmonics; these are safely concealed by this added flicker noise.
However, this is not the whole story. Notice that the chopper amplifier, having the 10 Hz narrow-band amplifier in the signal path, would amplify nothing if the total measurement time is 1 ms: the lowest measurable frequency with 1 ms measuring time is 1 KHz. So, we have to increase either the IF amplifier bandwidth, up to at least 2 KHz, or measurement time, up to 100 ms. These options are equivalent in principle as concerns simulation, and if you have a very performant number cruncher, you can increase the variable sim_time. I'm choosing to increase the amplifier bandwidth to 10 KHz. To visualize the input signal amplification, I feed the 2 KHz sinewave to the circuit input:

linear plots, zoomed in freq axis:

The input signal is amplified; 1/f flicker noise of IF amplifier is rejected; but harmonics appear anew in the output signal PSD. Unfortunately, the harmonics are unavoidable with chopper amplifiers, at least with this very simple realization as in my Python-coded model. Fortunately, their amplitudes are low, and a simple low-pass filter can be used to filter out these harmonics. The main goal is achieved with the chopper amplifier: a low-frequency component of flicker noise is safely suppressed.
The Python code used (with modifications as required) in simulations:
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import irfft, rfftfreq
import colorednoise
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# not exactly FIR, because the taps start BEFORE the sample being processed
def FIRbandpass(flow, fhigh, fs, tap_count):
    n = np.arange(-tap_count, tap_count+1)
    return 2*fhigh*np.sinc(2*fhigh*n/fs)/fs - 2*flow*np.sinc(2*flow*n/fs)/fs

sample_freq  = 100E6
time_per_sample = 1/sample_freq
chopper_freq = 1E6
samples_per_chop = int(sample_freq / chopper_freq)
sim_time = 1E-3
sample_count = int(sim_time * sample_freq)

# generate 100 realizations of pseudorandom 1/f noise
sim_count = 100;
flicker_noise_arr = colorednoise.powerlaw_psd_gaussian(1, (sim_count, sample_count) )
# sum and normalize these `sim_count` arrays into one sample_count-length array
flicker_noise = np.multiply(np.sum(flicker_noise_arr, axis=0), 1/float(np.sqrt(sim_count)))

t = [step * time_per_sample for step in range(0, sample_count)]
# 'pure' signal, which is fed to chopper1 signal input
sig = [np.cos(2 * np.pi * 2E3 * step / sample_freq) for step in range(0, sample_count)]
# waveform for the first chopper 'local oscillator (LO)' input
chopper1 = [np.sign(step % samples_per_chop - sample_freq/chopper_freq / 2) for step in range(0, sample_count)]

f = np.multiply(rfftfreq(sample_count), sample_freq)

# multiply LO signal (F_CHOP) and input (VI) fed to chopper1
# and add a flicker noise generated in the circuit
chopper1_out = np.multiply(sig, chopper1) + flicker_noise

# PSD at the chopper1 output (connected to Chopper_OP input)
psd1 = np.abs(irfft(chopper1_out, n=sample_count))**2

# draw three graphs. The first graph shows PSD at the chopper1 input: 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3)
fig.suptitle('Very narrow-band IF amplifier: f_low = chopper_freq - 5 KHz, f_high = chopper_freq + 5 KHz')
axes[0].set_title('chopper1 output signal PSD, 2 KHz sine fed to input')
axes[0].set_xlim(0, sample_freq/2/5);
axes[0].plot(f, psd1[0:f.size], color='cyan');

# waveform for the second chopper 'local oscillator', 180 degrees shifted chopper1 LO
chopper2 = [np.sign((step + samples_per_chop / 2) % samples_per_chop - sample_freq/chopper_freq / 2) for step in range(0, sample_count)]

# construct bandpass filter
tap_count = 100
bpflt = FIRbandpass(chopper_freq + 5E3, chopper_freq - 5E3, sample_freq, tap_count)

# Chopper_OP narrow-band 'intermediate frequency (IF)' amplifier gain
gain_IF = 1000
# filter out the first chopper output and amplify it with IF amplifier
chopper2_in = gain_IF * np.convolve(chopper1_out, bpflt, mode='same')

# next statement is essential for understanding my point: the 1/f 
# noise which you see at VO output is generated by Chopper_OP 
# and its connected output networks (capacitors and resistors) 
# which are outside the path of input signal that is mixed 
# with the chopper (IF) frequency (from chopper1_out to chopper2_in). 
# This flicker noise realization is constructed below and 
# put into variable `output_flicker_noise`.
# Once again, generate 100 realizations of pseudorandom 1/f noise
sim_count = 100;
output_flicker_noise_arr = colorednoise.powerlaw_psd_gaussian(1, (sim_count, sample_count) )
# sum and normalize these `sim_count` arrays into one sample_count-length array
output_flicker_noise = np.multiply(np.sum(output_flicker_noise_arr, axis=0), 1/float(np.sqrt(sim_count)))

# The low-freq 1/f noise of Chopper_OP is perfectly suppressed by 
# the bandpass filter, but some amount (1 percent) of additional 
# flicker noise is added to chopper2 output
chopper2_out = np.multiply(chopper2_in, chopper2) + 0.01 * output_flicker_noise

# PSD of the signal at the chopper2 output
psd2 = np.abs(irfft(chopper2_out, n=sample_count))**2
axes[1].set_title('chopper2 output signal PSD, 1/f noise, generated outside signal path in IF amplifier, ADDED')
axes[1].set_xlim(0, sample_freq/2/5);
axes[1].plot(f, psd2[0:f.size], color='magenta')

# PSD of the signal at the chopper2 output vs input signal PSD, loglog plot
psd0 = np.abs(irfft(sig, n=sample_count))**2
axes[2].set_title('chopper2 output signal PSD vs input signal PSD, 2KHz sine at input; flicker generated OUTSIDE IF amp is ADDED; loglog plot')
axes[2].set_ylim(1E-13)
axes[2].loglog(f, psd0[0:f.size], color='blue');
axes[2].loglog(f, psd2[0:f.size], color='orange');
plt.show()


Thank you very much for your reply. I sincerely appreciate it. As I am still quite new to the signal processing aspect of chopping, I may need some more time to understand the excellent simulations you have performed and the principles behind them. Should I have more questions or opinions, I will add more comments here.

'Signalprocessing' aspect of circuit design can be no less demanding than pure 'electronics' aspect.

You see that I was changing my mind in the course of searching explanation to your SPECTRE simulations, and even now both you and I admit of other possible interpretations. What is remarkable about your question is that it demonstrates that not only a high-speed end of circuit design poses challenges e.g. like metastability issues, clock and data recovery, oscillator stability; an opposite end of long-time processes where flicker noise dominates can also become a mine field especially when combined with high precision measurement requirements.

Thank you very very much for your explanation. I sincerely appreciate it. I will continue to have a look at relevant theories and to gain more understandings.
